# mysql triggers and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers

I just found the command to see my triggers: SHOW TRIGGERS

With phpmyadmin is there an area to see the triggers I have created?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the accepted answer was correct at the time, newer versions of phpmyadmin do now provide a couple of ways to view/edit triggers that have been created in a given database.

In the database table list, expand the list of objects underneath a table with a trigger, and along with columns and indexes, you will see triggers.  Expand triggers and click on a trigger you wish to examine, and you are given a dialog box to examine and edit the properties of the trigger.

There is also a tab called "Trigger" that appears across the top of the main frame whenever a database or table is selected in the left column which, when chosen, will display a list of triggers associated with the database or table selected in the side column.  Clicking on a list item will also bring up the view/edit dialog for that trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Currently phpMyAdmin can only browse databases, tables, views, columns, and indexes. The only way to view the list of triggers is to run the sql SHOW TRIGGERS that you mentioned.