# Sql not saving correct float values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am saving the thickness, length and width and coordinates of certain objects, all these values are floats.

When I try to save them into the sql database a value like 39.888 is saved as 1.0000000

I have changed the sql columns from double to float but it has not changed anything.

This is the code I am trying to upload into the database

```
INSERT INTO items (
  Cod, Date, TownHall, Parish, Place, 
  Epoch, RawMaterial, Description, Base, Technology, 
  Length, Width, Thickness, Latitude, Longitude, 
  Bibliography, Image) 
VALUES (
  1, '2019-05-17', 'Idanha-a-Nova', 'Ladoeiro', 'Oliveiras',
  'Idade do Bronze', 'Sílex', 'Indeterminado', 'Núcleo', 'Núcleo',
  2.9, 3.4, 0.8, 39.809484, -7.23707,
  'Apresenta Desgaste', @img)
```

1.000000000000 and -1.00000000 are shown insted of the correct values

[image]
[image]

Comment: That makes no sense.  Perhaps you have a trigger on the table.

Comment: Where I can see if I have a trigger?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218313/mysql-triggers-and-phpmyadmin

Comment: Right now they are floats

Comment: don't use float, it's unreliable, use `DECIMAL(x,y)` instead

Comment: Even with decimal it is not working!

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Gordon Linoff it makes perfect sense :) the given definition disallows any digits before decimal delimiter and floats are inaccurate (check my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `float` is unreliable and you should use `DECIMAL(x,y)` to store your coordinates instead.

Second thing, even when using `float`, your definition `float(x,x)` is incorrect. It basically means that there are `NO` digits before the decimal delimiter and `x` decimal digits. When trying to put `39.888`, you should get an error:

`ERROR 1264 (22003) at line x: Out of range value for column 'Latitutde'`

On some configurations it's only a warning and it tries to put the number nearest to allowed. That would be `0.99999(9)` or `-0.99999(9)`. But, as floats are inaccurate, it reads it as `1.0` and `-1.0`.

It should be `float(x,y)` where `x` is total allowed number of digits, and `y` is the number of decimal digits.

---

Long answer short:

*For example*: Use `DECIMAL(8,6)` so `39.809484` would work - it has 8 digits total, and 6 decimals.

Normally coordinates should be stored as:

lat - `DECIMAL(10, 8)` as it can be in range of -90 to +90 degrees

lng - `DECIMAL(11, 8)` as it can be in range of -180 to +180 degrees

Comment: @FlashThunder . . . I am used to getting errors when values don't fit into specified data types.  I'm surprised this is ever permitted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, normally it should throw an error, but some (annoying) configurations allow that, leaving only a notice

Comment: for example in glacial movement research even 0.1mm counts and as I said it is common to store 8 decimals as there are no GIS applications that are using better accuracy (if you know what GIS is), of course you could store it more accurately (and it is needed in some cases), but my example shows what is the common way of storing coordinates, everything else is explained in the answer above

Comment: @Wiimm By the way... It's not about 1.2mm. In most cases it differs in different regions and is highly dependable of a map projection being used.